# How to prove logical fallacy?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Any sum of two numbers is rational. The sum x+y is rational. Therefore, the numbers x and y are both rational.

Let $U$ be $\mathbb{R}$

$$
\begin{align*}
\\ p: x \in \mathbb{Q} \quad  y \in \mathbb{Q}
\\ q: x+y \in \mathbb{Q}
\\ 
p \to q & \quad Premise
\\ q & \quad Premise
\\ p & \quad Conclusion
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Do you mean "The sum of any two _rational_ numbers is rational"?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it's from textbook

Answer (score 2):

[Affirming the consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent) is the logical fallacy you're looking for. It does not follow that because the consequence necciserily implies the conditions.